postfix/master[2863]: fatal: fifo_listen: open public/pickup: Permission denied
I'm running postfix in kubernetes.   Specifically, I'm running docker-mailserver:14:0:0
when I start the container up, I'm getting the following permission error but have no idea what to do about it.
2024-08-31T20:35:42.996726+00:00 mailserver-5fbff4f658-qzkcm postfix/postfix-script[2862]: starting the Postfix mail system
2024-08-31T20:35:43.023547+00:00 mailserver-5fbff4f658-qzkcm postfix/master[2863]: fatal: fifo_listen: open public/pickup: Permission denied

This happens repeatedly in the logs of the container.
I've logged into the container and can see that
/var/spool/postfix/public/pickup    does exist as a named pipe (I did ls -la to see the attributes)
Here is the result of hte ls -la
p--------- 1 root root   0 Aug 31 20:45 pickup

if I delete pickup, it will be recreated again almost immediately, with the same problem.
dovecot is working, so I'm able to use imap to access the server and download my e-mails.
It's just that I cannot send or receive e-mails from the server.
can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

In case anyone comes across this post in the future.  I gave up and took an alternative solution.   As I'd managed to get Dovecot working enough to be able to log into the imap part, I decided to setup a completely new server using different mail software.   I was then able to move the existing e-mails from one server to the other using an e-mail client.    For me needs, this was good enough as I didn't have too many e-mail accounts on the server.    I'm no longer running my e-mail server on my kubernetes cluster.
